# How to get table cell value from QTableWidget in pyside?

Tags: python

`form_shift` is form name

`tblSession` is `QTableWidget` object

```
shift_id=form_shift.tblSession.item(1,0).text()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please post some more code so we can help you.

Answer (score 7):

This works just fine for me. Perhaps your table does not have an item at those coordinates?

```
table = QtGui.QTableWidget(5, 3, self)

for row in range(5):
  for col in range(3):
    table.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("(%d, %d)" % (row, col)))


print("1,0: %s" % table.item(1, 0).text())
```

Comment: In Pyside6 `QTableWidgetItem` is located in Pyside6.QtWidgets

Comment: @RikMulder In PyQt5 `QTableWidgetItem` is located in `PyQt5.QtWidgets` as well.